# Format of data in the .code/.text section

Tags: disassembly, malware, static-analysis

I'm attempting to dissect/disassemble a windows PE file under Linux using objdump.  On surface analysis, the .code section was disassembled to :

```
tmp.exe:     file format pei-i386


Disassembly of section CODE:

00401000 <CODE>:
  401000:       04 10                   add    $0x10,%al
  401002:       40                      inc    %eax
  401003:       00 03                   add    %al,(%ebx)
  401005:       07                      pop    %es
  401006:       42                      inc    %edx
  401007:       6f                      outsl  %ds:(%esi),(%dx)
  401008:       6f                      outsl  %ds:(%esi),(%dx)
  401009:       6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%edi)
  40100a:       65                      gs
  40100b:       61                      popa
  40100c:       6e                      outsb  %ds:(%esi),(%dx)
  40100d:       01 00                   add    %eax,(%eax)
  40100f:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
  401011:       00 01                   add    %al,(%ecx)
  401013:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
  401015:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
  ...
```

Then I looked at the entry point which was 0x45e534, which
ended up within an opcode:

```
  45e52f:       00 dc                   add    %bl,%ah
  45e531:       e2 45                   loop   0x45e578
  45e533:       00 55 8b                add    %dl,-0x75(%ebp)
  45e536:       ec                      in     (%dx),%al
  45e537:       83 c4 f0                add    $0xfffffff0,%esp
  45e53a:       b8 04 e3 45 00          mov    $0x45e304,%eax
  45e53f:       e8 e0 84 fa ff          call   0x406a24
```

Which, I feel is very wrong; but since my understanding of assembly is lacking, I could be wrong.

So having read [1] and the chapter on Disassembly in "Practical Malware Analysis", I realized that there could be data in the .text (or in this case, CODE) section.  So I took a gander at the
hex dump on the file and came across at the beginning of
the code section:

```
0000400: 0410 4000 0307 426f 6f6c 6561 6e01 0000  ..@...Boolean...
0000410: 0000 0100 0000 0010 4000 0546 616c 7365  ........@..False
0000420: 0454 7275 658d 4000 2c10 4000 0204 4368  .True.@.,.@...Ch
0000430: 6172 0100 0000 00ff 0000 0090 4010 4000  ar..........@.@.
0000440: 0107 496e 7465 6765 7204 0000 0080 ffff  ..Integer.......
0000450: ff7f 8bc0 5810 4000 0104 4279 7465 0100  ....X.@...Byte..
0000460: 0000 00ff 0000 0090 6c10 4000 0104 576f  ........l.@...Wo
0000470: 7264 0300 0000 00ff ff00 0090 8010 4000  rd............@.
0000480: 0108 4361 7264 696e 616c 0500 0000 00ff  ..Cardinal......
0000490: ffff ff90 9810 4000 0a06 5374 7269 6e67  ......@...String
...
```

This lead me to believe that there is definitely DATA in the code section [but, again, I could be wrong].

My question is (even given [1]), is it possible to figure out what the format of the DATA is in that part of the binary?

With my limited understanding, I'm guessing it's a structure of some sort *or* possibly a long list of DB/DW but (again, I could be wrong).

For instance, the very first set:

```
0410 4000 0307 426f 6f6c 6561 6e01 00 00..
```

Could the above be translated to something like (in assembly)

```
   DB 0x00401004
   DB 0x0703
   DB "Boolean"
   ...
```

I tried to look for the opcode DB in [2] but couldn't find it, so I'm wondering if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Any help/pointers appreciated

:ewong

[1] - [How do reverse engineers commonly detect the format of binary data?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16498/how-do-reverse-engineers-commonly-detect-the-format-of-binary-data)

[2] - http://mathemainzel.info/files/x86asmref.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

objdump disassembles linearly, it does not do control flow, so you may get gibberish in return. Use

```
objdump -f
```

to get the entry point, and use that address as `--start-address` argument.

Be aware — since it is linear, it will disassemble from this address till the end of the binary or end of the code section, so you may need to provide a `--stop-address`, too, if you don't want a seemingly endless spew.

```
:\>f:\mingw\bin\objdump.exe -f .\getinst.exe

.\getinst.exe:     file format pei-i386
architecture: i386, flags 0x0000012f:
HAS_RELOC, EXEC_P, HAS_LINENO, HAS_DEBUG, HAS_LOCALS, D_PAGED
start address 0x00404ee3 <<<<<<<<<
```

Disassembling some bytes from a specific address:

```
:\>f:\mingw\bin\objdump.exe -d --start-address 0x00404ee3 --stop-address 0x00404f00 .\getinst.exe

.\getinst.exe:     file format pei-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00404ee3 <.text+0x3ee3>:
  404ee3:       e8 0a 07 00 00          call   0x4055f2
  404ee8:       e9 74 fe ff ff          jmp    0x404d61
  404eed:       8b 4d f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%ecx
  404ef0:       64 89 0d 00 00 00 00    mov    %ecx,%fs:0x0
  404ef7:       59                      pop    %ecx
  404ef8:       5f                      pop    %edi
  404ef9:       5f                      pop    %edi
  404efa:       5e                      pop    %esi
  404efb:       5b                      pop    %ebx
  404efc:       8b e5                   mov    %ebp,%esp
  404efe:       5d                      pop    %ebp
  404eff:       51                      push   %ecx
```

If you notice, the instruction at `0x404eed` may never be executed as there is a hard-coded `jmp` which will divert the control flow, so all disassembly after the jmp might be gibberish and useless.

You may `need` to provide `0x404d61` as `--start-address` for following the flow as below:

```
:\>f:\mingw\bin\objdump.exe -d --start-address 0x404d61 --stop-address 0x404d80 .\getinst.exe

.\getinst.exe:     file format pei-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00404d61 <.text+0x3d61>:
  404d61:       6a 14                   push   $0x14
  404d63:       68 b0 9c 42 00          push   $0x429cb0
  404d68:       e8 53 0b 00 00          call   0x4058c0
  404d6d:       6a 01                   push   $0x1
  404d6f:       e8 d9 02 00 00          call   0x40504d
  404d74:       59                      pop    %ecx
  404d75:       84 c0                   test   %al,%al
  404d77:       0f 84 50 01 00 00       je     0x404ecd
  404d7d:       32 db                   xor    %bl,%bl
  404d7f:       88                      .byte 0x88
```

If you notice, you may still see gibberish at `0x404d7d`. That is because the provided stop-address is insufficient to decode the bytes into a sensible instruction.

```
:\>f:\mingw\bin\objdump.exe -M intel -d --start-address 0x404d7d --stop-address 0x404d8b .\getinst.exe

.\getinst.exe:     file format pei-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00404d7d <.text+0x3d7d>:
  404d7d:       32 db                   xor    bl,bl
  404d7f:       88 5d e7                mov    BYTE PTR [ebp-0x19],bl
  404d82:       83 65 fc 00             and    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x0
  404d86:       e8 90 02 00 00          call   0x40501b
```

Edit

```
db = define byte like  size(1)  "\xff"   
dw = define word like  size(2)  "\xff\xff"  
dd = define dword like size(4)  "\xff\xff\xff\xff"     
dq = define qword like size(8)  "\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff"
```

Answer (score 0):

Delphi executables store read only data such as RTTI (Run time type information) at the start of CODE section. `objdump` can’t know that it’s not really code so it tries to disassemble it as instructions and you get nonsense.